# How to lookup db data from a flink job

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am new to Apache Flink.

I am constructing a flink operator. There is a need to fetch data from a relational store to process the streaming data. This is a small quick lookup. I have used a spring-jdbc client to do lookups.

```
public class FilterCriteriaEvaluator extends KeyedProcessFunction<Long, DeviceAttrUpdate, FilterCriteriaEval> {


private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

public FilterCriteriaEvaluator(DataSource dataSource) {
    namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
...
```

However on executing this job on a cluster I get the following error

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
```

The spring db client is not serializable. I then considered using `java.sql.DataSource` directly. But this is not serializable as well.

Marking the db client transient doesn't help as it is then not serialized as a part of the operator object and I get an `NPE` while executing the job on the cluster.

What am I missing here? How can I do db lookups from a flink job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you can mark the `JdbcTemplate` as transient and make it lazy initializable - something like

```java
private transient JdbcTemplate instance = null;

// Not thread-safe
public JdbcTemplate getInstance() {
    if(instance == null){
        // init
    }

    return instance;
}
```

and access it via `getInstance()` method.
However, this way you will have a separate instance per each task slot.

In order to have a single instance per Task Manager, you can make it static variable. However, this way you will need to care about thread safety and make thread-safe initialiser.

Alternatively, you should again mark the variable `transient`, but instead of making `getInstance` field, extend from `RichFunction` (or whatever operation you have) and initialise the template in `open(Configuration parameters)` method, which gets called on initialisation and is suitable for one time setup work.

Comment: Thanks. For now I'm opting to do a lazy instantiation via the `open` of the `RichFunction`. But my streaming pipeline has many operators which would need this db client. I can create a static utility which instantiates a singleton. But I would typically prefer for the spring dependency injection to do this job. Is there some hook where I can bring up my spring application context on the flink cluster, specifically in the Task Manager JVM process? In case you are unfamiliar with the spring application-context it is a container which has all instances of objects needed in my application

Comment: @AbhijithMadhav , I don't think there is such facility.

Answer (score 1):

The mechanism that's built into Flink to make what you're doing easy is to do a [lookup join](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/joins/#lookup-join) using Flink SQL.

That would look something like this:

```sql
-- Customers is backed by the JDBC connector and can be used for lookup joins
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Customers (
  id INT,
  name STRING,
  country STRING,
  zip STRING
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'jdbc',
  'url' = 'jdbc:mysql://mysqlhost:3306/customerdb',
  'table-name' = 'customers'
);

-- enrich each order with customer information
SELECT o.order_id, o.total, c.country, c.zip
FROM Orders AS o
  JOIN Customers FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF o.proc_time AS c
    ON o.customer_id = c.id;
```

For more about the JDBC SQL connector, see [the docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/table/jdbc/).

Comment: Thanks for this. After a few more iterations of the prototype I realize that doing a db lookup might not be a good idea as the amount of lookup data might be huge(about 5B rows). This translates to a lot of lookups and a lot of load on db w.r.t. the rate of streaming events. What are the alternatives here? We could use a compacted kafka topic as our store. Can we do a lookup similarly there?